# Can this theory that internalize sets from external functions be consistent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

I want to know if the following theory stand a chance of being consistent?

$Language:$ Mono-sorted first order predicate logic + primitives of equality $``="$ and class membership $``\in"$:

Define: $set(x) \iff \exists y \, (x \in y)$

*Axioms:*

**Extensionality:** $\forall z ( z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \implies x=y$

**Class Comprehension:** $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \iff set(y) \phi)$; for any formula $\phi$ in which $``x"$ doesn't occur.

Define: $x=V \equiv_{df} \forall \text { set } y \, (y \in x)$

**Sets:** $\sf ZFC$$^V$

That is: all axioms of $\sf ZFC$ written with all of their quantifiers bounded $``\in V"$.

**Size:** $\forall x \in V (|x| \leq \aleph_\omega)$

**Exchange:** $\forall a,b \in V: |a|=|b| \to \\\exists f (f: a \to b \land bijection(f) \land \\ \forall k \in V [k \subseteq a \to  f``k \in V ] \, \land \\\forall l \in V  [l \subseteq b \to  f^{-1} ``l \in V] )$

Where: $f``x = \{f(y): y \in x\}$, and $f^{-1}= \{\langle b,a \rangle: \langle a, b \rangle \in f\}$

The point here is that the last axiom does add sets through the use of an *external* function! So sets are not just left a lone to be built after the set world ZFC rules. No! Sets can be constructed after external functions here.

> Can this theory be consistent???

Comment: To clarify, in the **size** axiom the functions witnessing $\vert x\vert\le\aleph_\omega$ need not in general be elements of $V$, but $\aleph_\omega$ is the thing $V$ thinks is $\aleph_\omega$, correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Yes! For example there is no bijection *in* $V$ from $\aleph_\omega$ to $\aleph_{\omega+1}$, but there is one externally! So there *is* a subset of $V$ that is a bijection from $\aleph_\omega$ to $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ yet it is NOT an element of $V$.